# Windows 2012 - Dynamic start screen definition

Tags: windows-server-2012

I do know, that i can predefine start screen by defining an xml file and pushing it via Grou Policy. What choices do i have if i want to define it at the logon moment? I'd like to ask our database at logon time of a user and then decide how to define a start screen - basicaly i want to to set a list of apps he can run from start screen as he logs on, not before.

Second question, there is a start screen, and there is an app screen below as i understand. Is it possible to hide / lock one of them (GPO, Registry, etc.)? Just for the sake of the simplicity, i do not want, that someone would be able to switch these screens and then find out, that some important apps are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a start menu at login by using group policy preferences - Create shortcuts in a GPO under *User Configuration - Preferences - Windows Settings - Shortcuts* and apply this to users as you wish. IIRC it will only show a shortcut to the user if the application is installed. We've tested this and it works for us across Windows 7, 8 & 10.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to populate it in real time when the user logs on, by asking an external database or active directory (which apps this particular user should have access for). It has to be defined earlier, and it's not easy to manage if you have really many user groups. I would like to avoid GPO.

Comment: @TomaszSzkudlarek oh yes, it's absolutely not what you asked for... just the closest I know how to get. Sorry about that but I hoped it would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It does looks like, there isn't an easy answer. Basicaly, Windows 2012 prevents from modyfing Start Screen by third-party apps in real time (only user is able to do this manually). And the Import-StartLayout PowerShell cmdlet is able to import Start Screens only in binary format. So, it's not possible, unfortunately. It could work with group policy though, by defining xmls for each of the user before they logon, but that's bizzarre idea. Second question is then obsolete.